# Vue dynamic image path (picture not shown)

Tags: image, vue.js, dynamic

I try to load different pictures dynamically. But it won't work yet. 
In template i have my img tag with the dynamic source-path:

```
 <template>
  <div id="test">
    <img src="require('../../assets/containermoduls/${pname}.png')" />
  </div>
</template>
```

here my data function:

```
<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
    pname: '2x5'
}
}
}
</script>
```

This is my folder structure:

```
-src 
--assets
---containermoduls
----2x4.png
--components
---p3component
----Page3Left.vue (where my code is from)
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I don't get any error messages on my console. Instead of a picture I see someting like an picture icon.

Answer (score 2):

You should use binding `:src` instead of `src`

```
<img :src="require('../../assets/containermoduls/${pname}.png')" />
```